# Pcapdroid not listing apps. How to fix?

Tags: android

I installed Pcapdroid and initially I could see all apps that were running on my Android. But now when I start it I can't see any apps. How do I refresh or adjust the settings so that I can see all the apps that are running. Stopping the app and restarting did not work.

I wanted to see al the apps running on my android and nothing showed up. So I pushed all the options and started and restarted.